# ngCordova [$injector:modulerr] error with Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to use `ngCordova` in my project. I've used bower and installed it, put the full `lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova-js` path after my Ionic Bundle and before Cordova in my `index.html` and here is my module:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
```

But this error appears:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngCordova due to: ......

I've put everything in the right place, updated everything, but this error keeps appearing, how can i solve it?

Comment: is it referenced in your index.html like so: `<script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: Please post your `index.html` and the full error stack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when you do not correctly load the javascript. Try referencing the ngCordova lib in your index

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

see the last line. If that does not help we need more information. Post your index html code and the full error you get that you left out after 'due to:'...